# texnansi-lmr12+20 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, texlive, texmaker

I am using Texmaker 2.2.1 and TeXLive 2009 on Ubuntu and have installed `texlive-latex-recommended`, `texlive-fonts-recommended`,
`texlive-latex-base`, `texlive-base`, `texlive-latex-extra`, `texlive-xetex`, and `lmodern` packages. I am getting the following error message:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2008/02/29 v1.9a microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman(RS))
**! Font csnameendcsname=texnansi-lmr12+20 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.**
<to be read again>
relax
```

TeX is able to find this file (see below). So I don't understand what TeXLive is complaining about.

```
kpsewhich texnansi-lmr12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/texnansi-lmr12.tfm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is not looking for `texnansi-lmr12`  but for `texnansi-lmr12+20`. This means that microtype tries to expand the font. Normally you get this type this error when you force microtype to expand fonts while generating a `dvi`.

Comment: That's right. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Well don't force microtype to use expansion or generate pdf instead of dvi. As you didn't provide an example it is impossible to give you more a detailed answer.